# Specific question on CSS Specificity

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have a very specific question on CSS Specificity, something which I could not clearly understand on;
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

If I have 2 selectors which define non-contradicting properties/attributes, will both of the attributes still get applied OR the way it works is, it just compares the selectors, without bothering what is defined inside them.

So if we have;

```
.menu1 {color:red}
p.menu1 {font-size:10px}
```

Here both the selectors refer to "menu1", but define unrelated attribues (color/font-size)

So my question is does the Specificity still matter and only 1 of the 2 will be considered ? My question is more about how the actual implementation happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in this case the specificity does not matter as you are simply adding an extra property to the `menu1` class, which isn't changing any existing rules. However, if you reverse the order of the rules and attempt to override `color`:

```
p.menu1 {color:blue}
.menu1 {color:red}
```

then the **less specific** rule `.menu1 {color:red}` *will not* override the **more specific** `p.menu1 {color:blue}`, even though the 'red' rule *appears after* the 'blue' rule (try it out).

Of course, if you change the second rule to `p.menu1 {color:red}` it will override, as the two rules would then have the same specificity.

Comment: You seem to have hit the nail on the head...Your answer is exactly what I was looking for...Thx a lot..

Answer (score 1):

In the article's overview, point 11 says:

> 11. The last rule defined overrides any previous, conflicting rules.

*(where "last rule" may be replaced with "last or most specific rule")*

So if there are different properties then nothing is overridden. The two rules are combined, so `p.menu1` will all have a font size of 10 pixels and be red in color. The second rule still has a more specific selector, but it's simply not relevant until you specify a common style that will potentially be overridden.

How all of this is done in implementation is, well, an implementation detail, so I don't know.

Comment: Bear in mind that elements with `class="menu1"` but are *not* `p` elements will only be red in color; their font size may not be 10 pixels because they won't respond to the `p.menu1` selector.